# switch from portrait to landscape using keystroke combination?

Tags: windows, display, keyboard-shortcuts

I work with Windows 10 and 2 monitors.
I am looking for a tool with which I can quickly change/switch the position (portrait / landscape) per monitor, using a keystroke combination.

Does anyone know a tool that can do this?

Thanks.

Gr,
M

Comment: Isn't it automatic as you swivel the display on its base?

Answer (score 0):

For both at the same time use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>arrows</kbd>

There is no shortcut for changing 1 display at a time but you can go to the Dislpay setting, mark the monitor you want to change (for me it's 1).
Then change the Display orientation to that display.

[image]

[image]